# Final results of ffmpeg installation are libraries with missing links

Tags: ffmpeg, linker

```
[poster@localhost lib]$ ldd libavfilter.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc6bbd0000)
    libswscale.so.4 => not found
    libpostproc.so.54 => not found
    libavformat.so.57 => not found
    libavcodec.so.57 => not found
    libswresample.so.2 => not found
    libavutil.so.55 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc796d79000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc796b5c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc79679b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc79742b000)
[poster@localhost lib]$ ldd libswscale.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe29572000)
    libavutil.so.55 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4cfdea3000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4cfdc87000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4cfd8c6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4cfe442000)
```

All of them are like that.
I'm a newb and don't know how to solve this. They're right next to each other.
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same. Setting and exporting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH made ldd find the other .so-files.
In my case I had put libavfilter.so in folder /usr/local/lib that was already listen in /etc/ld.so.conf but still didn't work without this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Recompile ffmpeg library with rpath like that:
LDFLAGS="-L. -Wl,-rpath,." ./configure --prefix... your ffmpeg configure options.